# Add a "Plus Sign (+)" to a histogram axis using truncated data

Tags: histogram, stata, axis-labels, x-axis

I have some data with a long tail, which has been truncated for a histogram. I would like to add a simple "+" sign to the final value of the x-axis on the histogram. Below is an example showing the setup.

```
sysuse auto
gen price_graph = price
replace price_graph =10000 if price_graph>10000
hist price_graph, start(0) width(1000)
```

Below is the result of the above code, with the "+" sign drawn in and highlighted where I would like to put it:
[image]

I could also see scenarios when data would be truncated from the left as well, so a robust solution would be easily applicable to both scenarios.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
hist price_graph, start(0) width(1000) xla(0(2000)8000 10000 "10000+")
```

You spell out that you want specific text as a specific axis label. You then (optionally) indicate what other labels you want.

Comment: To help those that come behind me, it took a little for me to understand exactly how to implement this beyond the given example. The idea is to include value and label pairs. The value is a number, and the label is the string. So to add a 0- label, I do the following: `hist price_graph, start(0) width(1000) xla(0 "0-" 2000(2000)8000 10000 "10000+")`